# C# Usb Device - Oral Camera Snap ButtonPress Event

Tags: c#, libusb, usbserial

I want to take snapshot when pressed oral camera snap button. I used `WndProc` function for monitor all event but when l pressed snap button, No event doesn't work. İ sniff usb camera usb port. when I pressed snap button, received 4byte data. Request type "Bulk or interrupt transfer", raw data "02 01 00 01", driver name "Usb Hub". But i can't use Usb Hub with c# serialport class. I found `libusbdotnet`, and sample Test_Bulk. But it doesn't work for my usb device. It returns `Win32Error:PipeTransferSubmit Ep 0x81 error`.

How can I catch this event? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. You can use "AForge.NET" library for capture hardware button event. You can examine library source code or "Snapshot Maker"(sample).

For library :
http://www.aforgenet.com/aforge/framework/

For Sample Source: 
http://aforge.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Samples/Video/Snapshot%20Maker/ (use with svn)